# Durandal Router, ASP.Net controller,Logout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, durandal, single-page-application

Is there a way to call a `logout` action backed by a asp.net controller when a SPA application is loaded using `Durandal`

Once `logged in`, the application allows the user to `logout` though a logout link

```
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

The URL changes to /logout but the logout controller is never called.

Any ideas, is durandal preventing the event from bubbling up ?

-Ken

Comment: I had similar issue and what I found was html5 push states api was the culprit.In my case this only happened in Chrome. So I turned off push states by this -> Sammy.Application.prototype.disable_push_state = true; and it worked. However did you try a click hander which sets window.location to the needed url as html5 push states is very good feature.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to specify the controller and action in the href. Something like this:

```
<a href="/account/logout">Logout</a>
```